# Install Hawtio with Apache Karaf

Tags: maven, osgi, apache-karaf, karaf, hawtio

I try to install Hawtio in Karaf by adding this line in karaf console:

```
feature:repo-add hawtio 1.4.67
```

But i got this message error :

```
Error executing cammand: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/unmarshaller/DOMScanner
```

Haw can i fix this problem ?

Karaf Version: 4.0.1

Comment: Just tested on karaf 4.0.7
feature:repo-add hawtio 1.4.67
feature:install hawtio-core
It worked fine. Can you check with 4.0.7?

Comment: It works fine for me, too. Mine is karaf 4.0.5.

Comment: Try to upgrade Karaf its maybe a bug/problem on that old version